# 'RawKeyboard.instance.keyEventHandler == null': is not true

Tags: android, flutter

```
_updateView(TrackedBarcode trackedBarcode, Quadrilateral viewLocation) {
    var shouldBeShown = viewLocation.width() > MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1;
    if (!shouldBeShown) {
      if (_trackedBarcodes.containsKey(trackedBarcode.identifier) &&
          _trackedBarcodes[trackedBarcode.identifier] == null) {
        return;
      }
      _trackedBarcodes[trackedBarcode.identifier] = null;
      _advancedOverlay.setWidgetForTrackedBarcode(null, trackedBarcode);
      return;
    }

    if (_trackedBarcodes[trackedBarcode.identifier] == null) {
      var bubble = ProductBubble(trackedBarcode.barcode.data ?? '', BubbleViewState(BubbleType.StockInfo));
      _trackedBarcodes[trackedBarcode.identifier] = bubble;
    
      _advancedOverlay.setWidgetForTrackedBarcode(bubble, trackedBarcode);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsTjl.png)

Comment: scandit scanner code

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: when i did scan barcode in scandit scanner then i found this type error.

Comment: Please refrain from using screenshots, consider including it in the question in plaintext, because some people (including myself) might not be able to see it.

Comment: Hello, any solution to this issue? I'am facing the same problem.